# Overscroll in Safari produces an incorrect scroll direction when bouncing back

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've found this code online to add a class to the header when scrolling up and down. On Chrome etc. everything works fine, but Safari has a feature to scroll above the content.

The problem is that in Safari on a Mac is that you can "overscroll" the content, you can scroll further up than the content, which results into the viewport bouncing back and activating the scrolling down event. Which then results in having the "header invisible" state while being at the top of the page.

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(event){
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (st > lastScrollTop){
        $('.header').addClass("header-invisible");
    } else {
        $('.header').removeClass("header-invisible");
    }
    lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

My question is how to solve this, or do i have to re-write this piece of code to make it work in safari?

i've tried searching for CSS solutions to disable the overscroll on a browser, but have failed getting an answer.

Comment: That’s a feature, not a bug. See [`overscroll-behavior`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/overscroll-behavior).

Comment: @SebastianSimon thanks for editing, i've changed the text a bit aswell.